# Cannot add foreign key constraint errno: 1215 sequlize/mysql

Tags: mysql, database, migration, sequelize.js, database-migration

So. I'm creating tables and while migrating i'm facing the error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
errno: 1215
sqlState: 'HY000',
sqlMessage: 'Cannot add foreign key constraint',
sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_questionnaire_contact\n' +
  "    (   user_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',\n" +
  "        del int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',\n" +
  "        id_questionnaire int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',\n" +
  "        contact char(1) COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',\n" +
  '        createdAt datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n' +
  '        updatedAt datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\n' +
  '        CONSTRAINT FK_UQContactUser FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,\n' +
  '        FOREIGN KEY (id_questionnaire) REFERENCES questionnaires(id),\n' +
  '        PRIMARY KEY (user_id, id_questionnaire)\n' +
  '    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;'
```

},

I'm using sequlize.js orm and sequlize:cli for migrating. Here is my model form where i'm getting an error.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('UserQuestionnaireContact', {
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    id_questionnaire: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '0',
      primaryKey: true
    },
    contact: {
      type: DataTypes.CHAR(1),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: '1'
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'users_questionnaire_contact',
    defaultScope: { attributes: { exclude: [ 'id'] } }
  });
};
```

My user model:

```
  module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Model = sequelize.define('User', {
      company_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Company',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },
      first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(512),
        allowNull: false
      },
      last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(250),
        allowNull: true
      },
      career_category_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: true
      },
      training_course_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true
      },
      country_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true
      },
      currency_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        allowNull: true
      },
    }, {
      tableName: 'users'
    });

    Model.associate = models => {
      Model.belongsTo(models.Currency, {foreignKey: 'currency_id', as: 'curr'});
      Model.belongsTo(models.Country, {foreignKey: 'country_id', as: 'country'});
      Model.belongsTo(models.CareerCategory, {foreignKey: 'career_category_id', as: 'career'});
      Model.belongsTo(models.TrainingCourse, {foreignKey: 'training_course_id', as: 'training_course'});
      Model.belongsTo(models.Company, {foreignKey: 'company_id', as: 'company'});
      Model.hasMany(models.Attempt, {foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'attempts'});
      Model.hasMany(models.UserQuestionnaireContact, {foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'u_q_contact'});
      Model.hasMany(models.UsersQuestionnaireAttemptLimit, {foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'u_q_limit'});
    };

  return Model;
};
```

And my questionaries table which is related to:

```
 const Model = sequelize.define('Questionnaire', {
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true,
      defaultValue: '0'
    },
  }, {
    tableName: 'questionnaires'
  });

  Model.associate = models => {
    Model.belongsToMany(models.Company, {
      as: 'questCompanies',
      foreignKey: 'questionnaire_id',
      otherKey: 'company_id',
      through: 'company_questionnaire_maps'});
    Model.hasMany(models.Attempt, {foreignKey: 'questionnaire_id', as: 'q_attempts'});
    Model.hasMany(models.QuestionGroup, {foreignKey: 'questionnaire_id', as: 'q_groups'});
    Model.hasMany(models.CompanyQuestionnaireMap, {foreignKey: 'questionnaire_id', as: 'company_questionnaire_maps'});
  };
```

Does somebody have any idea how to fix this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the table definitions for users and questionnaires.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you for response. I've added and thank you for answer in advance.